# Possible to alter form image and still send as file?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to alter a user uploaded image in javascript and still post the altered file as a file to the server rather than base64 representation?

I've been working with a library which base64 encodes an image and allows for cropping and rotating and such. It then posts the base64 string to the server which causes lots of headaches in browsers when you have multiple large files.

Edit:
Adding some sample code upon request. Just the current itteration of what I've tried.

```
.submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    window.fd = new FormData(e.target);

                    var imgs = (window.fd.getAll('icon[]') || []).map(function(str) {
                        return JSON.parse(str);
                    });

                    fd.delete('icon[]');

                    var promises = imgs.map(function(img) {
                        return fetch(img.output.image)
                            .then(function(res) { return res.blob() })
                            .then(function(blob) {
                                window.fd.append('icon[]', blob, 'filename')
                            });
                    });

                    $.when(promises).then(function() {
                        console.log('sending?');
                        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        oReq.open("POST", $('#ignite-campfire').attr('action'), true);
                        oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
                            console.log('tester', fd.getAll('icon[]'));
                        };
                        oReq.send(window.fd);
                    });
```

Comment: _"Is it possible to alter a user uploaded image in javascript and still post the altered file as a file to the server rather than base64 representation?"_ Yes it is possible. Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: I think the example is getting close it might just be making the request before attaching the new files.

Comment: The best solution would be to tweak the lib you do use so that it returns a Blob directly, thanks to the [`canvas.toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method, since I guess it does use a canvas to do the cropping, but you could also just convert again your dataURI version to a Blob and send this Blob in the FormData. (you can find a code of how to do this conversion in the [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Polyfill) section of previous link.

Comment: _"I've been working with a library which base64 encodes an image"_ Where are image files converted to `data URI`s?

Comment: @guest271314 just some library that the previous developers use. It just hijacks anything with the right class and does all the magic

Comment: @kaiido you are probably right but that isn't an option at the moment. Maybe I can fork it later.

Comment: @matthewdaniel Which portion of `javascript` at Question passes image to library? Have you found the line where image is converted to `data URI`?

Comment: @matthewdaniel, my comment was a two part comment. Read the second part, you can also only convert the dataURI to a Blob, even if it makes two useless computations, I personally do prefer to always post a Blob instead of a string.

Comment: @guest271314, this would not really crop the image, only its presentation. You won't be able to save the result.